# Why is taking the derivative inside of this improper integral justified? In proving variance of gaussian random variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals

In deriving the variance of a gaussian random variable $x$, following series of argument is used:

(1):  $var(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})dx$.

(2): The integral on RHS of (1) can be evaluated by differentiating w.r.t. $\sigma$ on the identity

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})dx = \sigma.
$$

(3): Then, the LHS and RHS become (after differentiating w.r.t. $\sigma$)

$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\frac{1}{\sigma^3\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})dx = 1.
$$

(4): Multiplying by $\sigma^2$ on both sides, I can recover $var(x) = \sigma^2$.

The step I am having trouble validating is the LHS from (2) to (3). I think what's going on is that the differentiation is done inside of the integral as follows:
$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma}\left((\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})\right)dx = 1.
$$
But I do not know how this is justified. Leibniz's rule does not seem to fit as the integral is improper.

Why and when is this okay?

[Need help with multi-variable calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103898/592293) is related but the reasoning in this answer is not understandable for me. Can I get a better answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\pm\infty$ limits are no problem since you can choose functions $g,\,h$ with$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(g(y))h(y)dy,$$e.g. $g(y):=\ln\frac{y}{1-y},\,h(y):=\frac{1}{y(1-y)}$, so$$\begin{align}\partial_\sigma\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\sigma;\,x)dx&=\partial_\sigma\int_0^1 f(\sigma;\,g(y))h(y)dy\\&=\int_0^1 \partial_\sigma f(\sigma;\,g(y))h(y)dy\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\partial_\sigma f(\sigma;\,x)dx.\end{align}$$

Comment: I've started over because I defined $g$ incorrectly in a way that would make further clarification by comments more confusing when I try changing it.

Comment: It seems to me that $\partial_\sigma\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\sigma;\,x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\partial_\sigma f(\sigma;\,x)dx$ is always true using this change of variables, without any assumptions required (other than the existence of derivatives w.r.t. $\sigma$). 

Am I correct in concluding this? If so, I am wondering why this is not a part of Leibniz's integral rule. Is there a known rule/theorem for this result?

Comment: @js9 The conditions needed for ap[plying the rule to integrals on $[0,\,1]$ still apply; I just made them implicit.

Comment: Which is just the assumption required for applying Leibniz's rule in general, right?